# Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit in different threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

`Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` are designed to be called from the same thread. But, what if I need to release a lock in a different thread than acquired?

For example: there are shared resource and asynchronous operation that uses this resource. The operation begins with `BeginOperation` and acquires the lock on the shared resource. There also the `EndOperation` method that releases the lock. `EndOperation` is typically called in another thread from a callback, thus I can't call `Monitor.Exit` in the `EndOperation` method. What is the best approach in this case? Will double-check locking with `AutoResetEvent` instead of `Monitor` be a good solution?

Comment: @pst Why specifically `Semaphore` and not `Event`?

Comment: See synchronization primitives like [Semaphore, SemaphoreSlim, ReaderWriterLock, ReaderWriterLockSlim, ManualResetEvent, ManualResetEventSlim, AutoResetEvent, CountdownEvent, Interlocked, Mutex etc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a ManualResetEvent, it's used to block thead(s) until some external event has been triggered. MSDN Doc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx

Answer (score 14):

The primitive you're looking for is called a [semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) which can be safely entered on one thread and exited from another.

Answer (score 8):

If you can use .NET 4.0 you can replace it with [System.Threading.Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) which allows you to acquire permits in one thread and release them in another.

> The Semaphore class does not enforce thread identity on calls to
>   WaitOne or Release.

Comment: If thread A takes the last open slot in a Semaphore and thread B signals a release... what would happen? This is a thing I don't understand in semaphores and don't know how/where to research it.