# Does .net guarantee to call Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am staring a TransactionScope and subscribe to `Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted`. To prevent issues with parallel transactions I use Monitor. Can I be sure that `Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted` would be called in any case?

```
Monitor.Enter(TransactionScopeLockString);

TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();

TransactionScope result = new TransactionScope(scopeOption, transactionOptions);

Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += (sender, transactionEventArgs) =>
{
    if (transactionEventArgs.Transaction.TransactionInformation.Status
                == TransactionStatus.Aborted)
    {
        // clear stuff
    }

    Monitor.Exit(TransactionScopeLockString);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is guaranteed though there might be one problem with your code. I remember that `TransactionCompleted` event is called on another thread so `Monitor.Exit` won't work. You cannot enter the monitor on one thread and exit it on another.

I believe you can use `ManualResetEvent` instead: [Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit in different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001760/monitor-enter-and-monitor-exit-in-different-threads)