# Using a Monitor lock in async or sync operations

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-7.0

I am trying to come with a solution for locking a global resources in a way that mandate locking for access and that is usable for sync or async operations.

I created a general class State:

```
public class State<T>
{
  public class LockedState : IDisposable {
    public LockedState(State<T> state) { this.state = state; Monitor.Enter(this.state.theLock); } // would be great if this could be private
    public void Dispose() => Monitor.Exit(this.state.theLock);
    public ref T Val { get { return ref state.t; } }

    readonly State<T> state;
  };

  public State() { }
  public State(T t) { this.t = t; }
  public LockedState Locked { get { return new LockedState(this); } }
  readonly object theLock = new object();
  T t;
}
```

The idea here is that I can have a global 'store' ie in the Program class:

```
public class Program {
    static public readonly State<ImmutableList<int>> TheList = new State<ImmutableList<int>>(ImmutableList<int>.Empty);
    static public readonly State<SomeType> SomeType = new State<SomeType>(SomeType());
}
```

and then the *only* way to access the state is by acquiring the lock like this:

```
using (var lTheList = Program.TheList.Locked) {
   lTheList.Val = lTheList.Val.Add(5));
}
```

which in my case works much better than a normal lock as it forces locking before get/set (you cannot forget to lock)

(side note is this a good strategy ?)

The issue is I cannot use the above in async code:

```
using (var someType = Program.SomeType.Lock()) {
   var x = await someType.Val.SomeAsyncOp();
}
```

I get an exception: `Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code`

I found this post [How to protect resources that may be used in a multi-threaded or async environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011179/how-to-protect-resources-that-may-be-used-in-a-multi-threaded-or-async-environme/21011273#21011273) which has an AsyncLock class However I couldn't understand how to fit a class like AsyncLock into my StateLock class ..

Can `State.Lock()` return a locked state that is usable for both sync and async callers ? that is really what I am looking for !

If not what is my best way forward ? using `SemaphoreSlim` and having a `State.Lock()` and a `State.AsyncLock()`  ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you dont use the `lock`-statement? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: Not completely sure if the using statement (so the try/finally block it makes) prevents this but I think the problem is the following: the thread that executes the code before the await (acquiring the lock) can be a different thread then the thread the executes the code after the await (releasing the lock). Since Monitor is re-entrant I think it tracks which thread owns the lock, I can imagine this error being thrown when another thread then the owning thread tries to release the Monitor.

Comment: knoop yes that is the problem .. how can I best solve it ?

Comment: Ah sorry, thought you where unclear as to why this error occurred. As mentioned in the thread you linked semaphore seems to be the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001760/monitor-enter-and-monitor-exit-in-different-threads.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `Monitor` here, as `Monitor` (aka `lock`) is inherently thread-based and requires you to "exit" the lock from the same thread that *acquired* the lock - which is exactly the situation you *rarely expect* in `async` code. Instead, consider a `SemaphoreSlim`, from which you can take and release a token, but which is *not* thread-bound.

Pseudo-code:

```
// usually a field somewhere
SemaphoreSlim obj = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

// acquire lock:
obj.Wait(); // or await obj.WaitAsync() if want async acquire

// release lock:
obj.Release(); // often in a "finally"
```

Comment: ok does that mean SemaphoreSlim is not reentrant ? that will make it unusable for me ...

Comment: @kofifus I *tried* to say "try `ReaderWriterLockSlim` - that has recursion support", but upon consideration that might be thread-bound too

Comment: ok so there is no asynchronous lock which is reenrtrant within the same thread and within all async operation from that thread ?

Comment: @kofifus not AFAIK, no; you might need to engineer something using the async call-content, but... that's not fun; it would be easier to remove the need to be re-entrant

Comment: ok I have no idea how to engineer such a thing ... seems something handy .NET should have ... thanks for the input!

Comment: upon further thinking I'm not sure such lock is even possible ...

Comment: @kofifus Well if you think of the monitor as working with a key (in this case the key is always the id of the thread that owns the lock) there should be a possibility of creating something where you can pass a key around and if you call the lock with the matching key you'll be able to re-enter it. That way you don't rely on programmers having to check if they already own a lock but it would mean that you're passing around a key everywhere in your code that uses this locking. So it should certainly be possible, the question is whether it is desirable:-)

Comment: I guess I'm worried about deadlocks especially if mixing sync and async code .. not sure.. also see http://asherman.io/projects/csharp-async-reentrant-locks.html

Answer (score -2):

You code is a worry because any malicious programmer can take a `lock` on `Program.TheList.Lock()` without calling `.Dispose()` and thus causing any future callers from getting stuck inside the constructor. Constructors should always execute fast and cleanly to avoid corruption to the run-time.

Your code is all kinds of code smell.

It's better to pass lambdas into your code and lock around that.

Try this code:

```
public class State<T>
{
    public State() { }
    public State(T t) { this.t = t; }

    private T t = default(T);
    private readonly object theLock = new object();

    public void With(Action<T> action)
    {
        lock (this.theLock)
        {
            action(this.t);
        }
    }

    public void Update(Func<T, T> action)
    {
        lock (this.theLock)
        {
            this.t = action(this.t);
        }
    }

    public R Select<R>(Func<T, R> action)
    {
        lock (this.theLock)
        {
            return action(this.t);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, along with your `Program` class, you can do this:

```
Program.TheList.Update(t => t.Add(5));
```

Less code and simpler.

You can also do this:

```
async void Main()
{
    var wc = new State<WebClient>(new WebClient());

    string source = wc.Select<string>(x => x.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com")));

    Console.WriteLine(source);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In the context of `async`, this just isn't true or helpful; for example, your `SelectAsync` without an `await` (that you **cannot** use, for good reason): doesn't lock over the correct interval - it only holds the lock until the first incomplete awaitable operation.

Comment: 'Less code and simpler' yes in above cases but not when the code inside the using (or your 'with') is doing a lot of it's own access to the state .. you'll end up with a very deep lambda nesting ...

Comment: @kofifus - This is the approach LINQ takes and that doesn't end up with deep lambda nesting.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Sorry, I was overreaching there with the async code. I've removed it.

Comment: I don't understand what Linq has to do with it .. with your approach you will have to be very careful inside your with or update that you're not using stale values which IMO is even more error prone than forgetting to lock .. anyways

Comment: @kofifus - What stale values?